# Alternative to collection group query on Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I intend to query all the documents in a collection to output one result (username). From my research, this feature isn't available yet on Firestore. What alternative do I have?

I am making an Android app that lets users query the database with a phone number, and get the username that is linked with the phone number they searched for. There are only 2 fields in each document: `Phone number` and `Username`.

Whenever a user searches for a phone number, every document in the collection should be queried until that phone number is found and the username linked to the phone number is returned as the result.

How do I go about this? I'd also appreciate other alternative to Firestore.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing how you would like to structure your data for a collection group query, it's impossible to know how to express an alternative.  Could you edit your question to be specific about what you can't do that requires an alternative?

Comment: Its easy you can match the mobile number with every document in a collection and if a match is found you can gets the uid of that document. Then using that uid you can retrieve the username of that user.

Comment: @Raj how do i match the mobile number with every document. I don't understand

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited the question, i hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Try to use whereEqualTo() clause to match mobile number. I can help you in a more better way if you post the code you have tried and the firestore db structure @OseMars.

Comment: Collection group queries are now available: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a database that looks similar to this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
       |
       --- userId (document)
             |
             --- phoneNumber: 123456789
             |
             --- userName: "UserName"
```

To get the user name of a user according to his phone number, you need to use a query. So for that, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
Query query = usersRef.whereEqualTo("phoneNumber", 123456789);
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String userName = document.getString("userName");
                Log.d(TAG, userName);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
UserName
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex Mamo. It worked. I replaced QueryDocumentSnapshot with DocumentSnapshot because QueryDocumentSnapshot wasnt recognized on my IDE. God bless you.